# fscanf returns -1, fgets returns 0 but fopen is working, what is the problem?

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, scanf

I am trying to read line by line and put the values on an integer that I will use later on. I used fgets and it returned 0 and did not go into the while loop, now I am using fscanf and it returns -1 and I can't get into the while loop too. I will insert the code segment and the text files I use here.

```
    FILE *f;
    f = fopen( fileNames[i], "r");
    if (f == NULL) {
        printf("Failed to open a file\n");
    }
                
    int number;

    printf("fscanf value %d\n", (fscanf( f, "%d", &number))); //returns -1 always
    while( fscanf( f, "%d", &number) > 0){ // does NOT get into the while loop
        for(int i = 0; i < intervalCount; i++){
            if( // operations I use in my project ){
                // operations that I will use in my project
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(f);
```

text files are something like

```
1534
1535
1420
1400
1600
1601
2500
1536
1537
1538
```

please help, I seriously don't understand what is the problem.

For some clarification - f is not NULL, it does not go into the if statement.

Comment: The `-1` is `EOF` perhaps a different file is being opened to the one you wanted: an empty one of the same name but different location.

Comment: How can I specify the location? I open the terminal in the doc where all my c files and all the text files are in that's why I never thought I should specify. Also I don't think there is another file with the same name in my computer :(.

Comment: Change the names to something you are *certain* is unique. `fopen` will use the "current working directory" which might not be where you think (unless you specify the full pathname).

Comment: that makes sense, but I tried it rn and didn't work :(

Comment: In that case please post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as text, the shortest *complete* code that can be copy/pasted, compiled and run *as is* to reproduce the probem.

Comment: My suspicion is that perhaps there's a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) at the beginning of the file that stops `scanf()`'s conversion. Did the file originated on Windows (and you are using Un\*x)? Try `hexdump -C filename.txt |head`

Comment: to debug, change fscanf to fgets and print the first line of text from the file.

Comment: @sarpoc Try `printf("<%d>\n", fgetc(f));` before `printf("fscanf ....`.  Pease report the result.

Answer (score 1):

You should exit from the function if `fopen()` fails, otherwise you have undefined behavior when calling `fscanf()` with a null pointer.

More generally, you should output more information in diagnostic messages to help find why these calls fail.

Single stepping in a debugger is a good approach too.

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

[...]

    FILE *f;
    f = fopen(fileNames[i], "r");
    if (f == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open file %s: %s\n",
                fileNames[i], strerror(errno));
    } else {
        int number;
        int res = fscanf(f, "%d", &number);
        if (res != 1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "reading from %s: fscanf returns %d\n",
                    fileNames[i], res);
        } else {
            while (fscanf(f, "%d", &number) == 1) {
                for (int i = 0; i < intervalCount; i++) {
                    if (// operations I use in my project) {
                        // operations that I will use in my project
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        fclose(f);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, but that is not the problem, f is not NULL in my case

Comment: @sarpoc: Then can you post a complete program that exhibits the unexpected behavior?

Comment: what does that mean? The complete program is 500+ lines long and this is where the problem exists, only file operations are here and fscanf is the problem.

Comment: Still you should fix this problem. `fscanf()` returns `-1` if there is a read error or more likely if the end of file has been reached.

Comment: @sarpoc: you should make a copy of the program and remove parts of it until the problem disappears. Once you have a minimal program that exhibits the problem, it will be much simpler to find the bug.

Comment: I still don't understand, since I wrote the code it started from a minimal program that was working. The problem started here, in fscan part. Which is like 40 lines. It works fine if I delete this part. What are you trying to say I don't get it. I included the text file too. What should I include more?

Comment: You should remove *other* parts. Maybe add hard coded filenames. Only use 1 instead of a whole array, etc. Remove everything not related to reading these files. But enough to compile it and run it.